# How to retrieve first N and last M lines from input in fish?

Tags: sed, awk, fish

I have an input like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

And I'd like to retrieve only N first and M last lines from this input.

For example, if N is 2 and M is 4 I want the result to be:

```
1
2
5
6
7
8
```

Lines can overlap, so if N is 6 and M is 4 I want the output to be equal to my input.

I have tried using awk, with no luck:

```
cat input | awk "{if (NR<2 || NR>count - 4) {print}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one technique:

```
$ seq 10 > input
$ set N 2; set M 4
$ set wanted (sed $N'q' input; tac input | sed $M'q' | tac)
$ printf "%s\n" $wanted
```

```
1
2
7
8
9
10
```

If `N+M > num_lines` then you will get duplicate lines with this approach.

**Or**, use fish's array subscripting:

```
$ set lines (cat input)
$ printf "%s\n" $lines[1..$N] $lines[(math (count $lines) - $M + 1)..-1]
```

```
1
2
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: The second approach produces `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`. I am looking for a one-liner: `set lines (cat /tmp/test); printf "%s\n" $lines[1..$N] $lines[(math (count $lines) - $M + 1)..-1]`

Comment: You need to set the `N` and `M` variables to resolve the syntax errors: `set N 2; set M 4; set lines ...`

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
awk 'NR <= 2 || lines - 4 < NR {print}' lines=(wc -l input) input
```

Since awk cannot possibly know number of lines in a file before it reaches end of file, you need to input the number of lines as a variable to awk.

Comment: nope, didn't work for me ):

Comment: Note that this is fish and so `$(...)` will not work. `cat /tmp/test | awk 'NR <= 2 || lines - 4 < NR {print}' lines=(wc -l)` prints the whole file

Comment: Updated answer for `fish`